# MP1584EN Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

[image]

i found this schematic in Datasheet .
what is 'C6' value Here ? What is Mean of 'NS' ?

how Can i get 5.5 volt in output .

Comment: NS might mean "Not Soldered"

Comment: @EnricoMigliore what is the usage?

Comment: It may be used as a filter for stabilty or for improving transient behavior.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore can i left it unconnected?

Comment: Yes, that is what they are telling you to do.

Comment: Yes, you may leave it unconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have the data sheet, see table 3 in the "Compensation Components" section.
For those typical uses C6 is listed as "None". So NS could very well mean Not Soldered, (as answered above).
Further in that same section it tells you how to determine if C6 is needed and how to determine the value.

To achieve a 5.5 volt output start with the typical application schematic of Figure 4 (5V Output).
The output voltage is determined by the resistor divider of R1 and R2 connected to the FB pin.
Use the calculation in the "Setting the Output Voltage" section to select R1 and R2.
You could start with the values as shown in Figure 4, then change R1 to a 180K with a 50K pot in series, then adjust the output to the needed 5.5V.
For fixed values, using R1=194K and R2=33K will come very close to 5.5V. You would need to determine your design tolerances.

I referenced this data sheet:
https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP1584/document_id/204

Comment: It use to indicate Not Selected (NS) indicating the designer had to select it for the performance he wanted.